# appending data to XML gives no protocol error in java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am writing contents to an xml file. The contents involve names of Person ,Organization & location . Now if the files is  not present , a new file is created and contents are written to it .This process works absolutely fine .

But, if a files already present, and I try to add content to it ,I get : No protocol  error .

I guess the problem is with appending files to already created XML files. After some search I got to know that the problem is with DocumentBuilder.parse(). So I also tried using :

Document document = documentBuilder.parse( new InputSource(new StringReader(filename+".xml")));
But still the error exists .

Can anyone help me out? 
Here's my code:

```
public static void xml_writer(ArrayList<String> per_names,ArrayList<String> loc_names,ArrayList<String> org_names,String filename,Logger L,Logger L1)
{   File file = new File(filename+".xml");
    // if file doesnt exists, then create it        
    if (!file.exists()) 
    {
        try { 
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();         
            Element rootElement = doc.createElement("Nouns");
            doc.appendChild(rootElement);
            Element staff = doc.createElement("Per_Names");
            for (int i=0;i<per_names.size();i++)
            {                       
                rootElement.appendChild(staff);  
                Element firstname = doc.createElement("Name");
                firstname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(per_names.get(i)));
                staff.appendChild(firstname);    
            }       
            staff = doc.createElement("Org_Names");
            for (int i=0;i<org_names.size();i++)
            {   
                rootElement.appendChild(staff);  
                Element firstname = doc.createElement("Name");
                firstname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(org_names.get(i)));
                staff.appendChild(firstname);    
            }
            staff = doc.createElement("Loc_Names");
            for (int i=0;i<loc_names.size();i++)
            {   
                rootElement.appendChild(staff);  
                Element firstname = doc.createElement("Name");
                firstname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(loc_names.get(i)));
                staff.appendChild(firstname);    
            }
            // write the content into xml file
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD,"xml"); 
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);
            transformer.transform(source, result);     
            //System.out.println("File saved!");
            L.info("writing to xml file successfull: "+filename);
        } 
        catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            L.info("Error : writing to xml file unsuccessfull :"+filename);
            L.info("Error : "+pce.getLocalizedMessage());
            L1.info("Error : writing to xml file unsuccessfull :"+filename);
            L1.info("Error : "+pce.getLocalizedMessage());
            pce.printStackTrace();
            } 
        catch (TransformerException tfe) {
            L.info("Error : writing to xml file unsuccessfull :"+filename);
            L.info("Error :"+tfe.getLocalizedMessage());
            L1.info("Error : writing to xml file unsuccessfull :"+filename);
            L1.info("Error :"+tfe.getLocalizedMessage());
            tfe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    else
    {   try
        {
        System.out.println("filealready exists");
            DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            //Document document = documentBuilder.parse( new InputSource(new StringReader(filename+".xml")));//new InputSource((filename+".xml"))); 
            Document document = documentBuilder.parse(filename+".xml");
        Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
        // Root Element   
        Element server = document.createElement("Per_Names");
        for (int i=0;i<per_names.size();i++)
        {                   
            Element name = document.createElement("Name");
            name.appendChild(document.createTextNode(per_names.get(i)));
            server.appendChild(name);       
            root.appendChild(server);
        }
        server = document.createElement("Org_Names");
        for (int i=0;i<org_names.size();i++)
        {                   
            Element name = document.createElement("Name");
            name.appendChild(document.createTextNode(org_names.get(i)));
            server.appendChild(name);       
            root.appendChild(server);
        }
        server = document.createElement("Loc_Names");
        for (int i=0;i<loc_names.size();i++)
        {                   
            Element name = document.createElement("Name");
            name.appendChild(document.createTextNode(loc_names.get(i)));
            server.appendChild(name);       
            root.appendChild(server);
        }

        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        L.info("writing output to xml successfull :"+filename);
        } 
    catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        L.info("Error : writing to xml file unsuccessfull :"+filename);
        L.info("Error : "+pce.getLocalizedMessage());
        L1.info("Error : writing to xml file unsuccessfull :"+filename);
        L1.info("Error : "+pce.getLocalizedMessage());
        pce.printStackTrace();
        } 
    catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        L.info("Error : writing to xml file unsuccessfull :"+filename);
        L.info("Error : "+tfe.getLocalizedMessage());
        L1.info("Error : writing to xml file unsuccessfull :"+filename);
        L1.info("Error : "+tfe.getLocalizedMessage());
        tfe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        L.info("Error : writing to xml file unsuccessfull :"+filename);
        L.info("Error : "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
        L1.info("Error : writing to xml file unsuccessfull :"+filename);
        L1.info("Error : "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        L.info("Error : writing to xml file unsuccessfull :"+filename);
        L.info("Error : "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
        L1.info("Error : writing to xml file unsuccessfull :"+filename);
        L1.info("Error : "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Based on what you appear to be doing, you need to find say Loc_Names, if it's not there, create and then append the children, if it is just append the children to the existing node. If it were me I'd load the current document into some class, append the 'new' stuff into the instance and then write out the full thing, unless it's a huge document, in which case things get more complicated...

Comment: @TonyHopkinson : Every time I just create a new node of say Loc_names ,Per_names,etc , so that I get to know what has been recently added . And also, for that I need not check wether Loc_names,Per_names,Org_names are empty or not !

Comment: Hmmm, not something I'd have done but okay...